How to stop an AirTag from beeping when not near iPhone?
I use all Apple devices, and my partner uses all Android devices - let's assume that won't change.
I have put AirTags on various suitcases etc. My partner went to stay many miles away for a week. According to them, after a week or so the AirTags on these items beeped annoyingly even though they were not being moved. My partner is now back home and the devices do not seem to be beeping.
Is there a way that I can use AirTags on items that can be moved by either of us, without them beeping and without my partner having an Apple device? Is there, for example, an Android app they can run? Alternatively, is there a way to shut the beeping up while my partner is traveling alone?
(I am aware that we may be running into anti-stalking protection or something, but my partner is quite aware of these AirTags and has indeed threatened to liquidise them!)

According to Apple (https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT212227)

An AirTag, AirPods Pro (2nd generation) charging case, or Find My network accessory that isn't with its owner for a period of time will emit a sound when it's moved.

AirTags are programmed to emit a sound when moved after being separated from the paired owner after a period of time. (You're correct in your assumption it's a stalking protection feature).
As of right now, there is no way to stop the beeping and keep the tracking feature active.
The Airtag can either be temporarily disabled by removing the battery which stops the beeping and stops the tracking capabilities. Or your partner keeps an iOS device nearby that supports the find my network (cheap supported iPod touch for example) and you share that AirTag with their Apple ID.
Apple doesn't have a middle option where tracking is enabled and it doesn't make a sound when not with its original owner.
There is an Android app from Apple called Tracker Detect that does allow an Android user to locate a nearby AirTag by purposely making it beep to locate it, but there's no further capabilities beyond that at this moment.
Software aside. You could just tape or saran wrap the AirTags so that the sound is greatly reduced that way they are less bothersome by putting pressure on the metal backside (where most of the sound comes from) until back from your trip. But that's a bandaid solution.

Thanks. I'm fine with disabling them, but I can't see a way to disable them other than to "remove" them, which presumably means I then can't re-enable them (remotely) in order to track luggage as my partner returns through the airport (at which stage the beeping is not an issue). Is there some other sort of "disable"?

@abligh You could either remove it from your AppleID through the Find My app or just remove the batteries which is probably the easiest out of the bunch that way when you're ready to use them again you just put the batteries back in. You can follow the Apple support link in the answer for more info on disabling it.

The only solution is to pry the Airtag open and remove the speaker, as explained in How can I deactivate the speaker on the Airtags?.
I ended up disabling the speaker on most of my Airtags as I keep them in the same location (i.e. my car's side door) and never need the beeping feature to locate them.

The only way to achieve what you want is to do a hardware hack. It takes prying the case open and disabling or removing the speaker. With a large possibility of destryoing the airtag.
